# Display lines in reverse order fgetcsv

Tags: php

How do I display lines in reverse order?

CSV file:

> column1;column2;column3
>
> cell1;cell1;cell1
>
> cell2;cell2;cell2
>
> cell3;cell3;cell3

It should appear like this:

> column1;column2;column3
>
> cell3;cell3;cell3
>
> cell2;cell2;cell2
>
> cell1;cell1;cell1

Code:

```
if (($handle = fopen($path, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{   
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead>';  
    // Get headers
    if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $data).'</th></tr>';
    }
    echo '</thead><tbody>';
    // Get the rest
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $data).'</td></tr>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: posted this comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect first

```
$collect = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
{
  $collect[]= '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $data).'</td></tr>';
}
echo implode(PHP_EOL,array_reverse($collect));
```

Reverse the array at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here what you need to do: instead of direct `echo`ing row - store it to a variable:

```
// Get the rest
$rest = '';
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
{
    // main trick here - add every new row BEFORE old ones
    $rest = '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $data).'</td></tr>' . $rest;
}
// echo gathered data
echo $rest;
```